# VB.NET / C# after finding installed Software names and application path how to find exe name

Tags: vb.net, list, exe, installed-applications

This code gets all software that has an Uninstall Entry and it app path. However, given I have the app path, I do not know the name of the main .exe of the software. What ways are there to find the main .exe of a found application?

```
   'Declare the string to hold the list:
    Dim Software As String = Nothing

    'The registry key:
    Dim SoftwareKey As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
    Using rk As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey)
        'Let's go through the registry keys and get the info we need:
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        For Each skName As String In rk.GetSubKeyNames()
            Using sk As RegistryKey = rk.OpenSubKey(skName)
                Try
                    'If the key has value, continue, if not, skip it:
                    If Not (sk.GetValue("DisplayName") Is Nothing) And Not (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") Is Nothing) And
                    Not (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") = "") Then
                        Dim instanceremoved As Boolean = False
                        For Each item As ListViewItem In ListInstalled.Items
                            If item.SubItems.Item(1).Text = sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") Then
                                item.Remove()
                                instanceremoved = True
                            End If
                        Next

                        If instanceremoved = False Then
                            Dim itemAdd As ListViewItem = ListInstalled.Items.Add(sk.GetValue("DisplayName"))
                            itemAdd.SubItems.Add(sk.GetValue("InstallLocation"))

                        End If

                    End If
                    'No, that exception is not getting away... :P
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex)
                End Try
            End Using
            j = j + 1
        Next
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

The main Exe is not stored in the registry the uninstall command is stored in the UninstallString key.

Comment: in different places on the filesystem not in the registry

Comment: yes, but is there some standard way to retrieve the main exe names of installed software or must the user choose it himself?

Comment: You can search for all the exe's but windows does not know about them unless you want to dig through the startmenu only thing it knows about in the registry is how to uninstall